# Lower Navigation speed in react-native

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am at the moment developing a mobile app by react native. I used react native navigation for navigating in my app .but when I navigate in my screen, the speed very very slow. I've seen in the past the link below
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html
But this document could not help me. I want you to help me with this problem.
what a solution whole you recommend to me?

Answer (score 0):

If you only have this issue in debug mode and not in release mode, I had the same issue and I fixed it by [disabling remote js debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50531400/5359812)